# Proper title structure on a webpage?

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, title, page-title

I have a website with the front page title structured like this:

```
<title>Site Name - The Subtitle</title>
```

For SEO purposes, is this the right way to structure the title or is it:

```
<title>The Subtitle - Site Name</title>
```

I'm using WordPress SEO by Yoast plugin to structure the titles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what your goal is. The latter might help with people searching "the subtitle", the former with "Site Name".

Realistically, though, that won't make a difference. The biggest thing is that users want to be able to see "The Subtitle" in the tab on their screen, whereas "Site Name" doesn't provide as much useful information. Therefore it's best to put "The Subtitle" first.